# How to loop through rows columns in e2e test

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end, e2e-testing

I am trying to test the content of my table and I need to loop through all rows and columns in order to accomplish that. My current code is:

```
it('test', function () {
        var appRowLocator = by.repeater('appRow in model.getAppList()');

        browser.wait(function () {
            return element(appRowLocator).isPresent();
        }, 1000);

        var i = 0;
        element.all(appRowLocator).then(function(rows){
            expect(rows.length).toBe(2);
            while(i < 2){
                rows[i].all(by.tagName('td')).then(function(cols){
                    expect(cols.length).toBe(8);
                        expect(cols[0].getText()).toBe(summary.applicationSummaries[i].application.name);
                        expect(cols[2].getText()).toBe("");
                });
                i++;
            }
        })
    });
```

I am accessing the content of cells, but test still fails because counter is incremented inside rows[i].all(....). My rows length is two as that is expected, and that expectation passes, but I am still confused why is counter incremented also inside rows[i].all(...). The error I am getting is:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'application' of undefined

And it's because it is trying to access application with index 2, and there is no that element in array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `then()` here. Use `get()` and let `expect()` resolve promises for you:

```
var cells = rows[i].all(by.tagName('td'));

expect(cells.count()).toEqual(8);
expect(cells.get(0).getText()).toBe(summary.applicationSummaries[i].application.name);
expect(cols.get(2).getText()).toBe("");
```

Comment: yes, but then I am getting Failed: Cannot call method 'getText' of undefined

Comment: element.all(appRowLocator).then(function(rows){
                expect(rows.length).toBe(2);


                for(var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i){

                    var cells = rows[i].all(by.tagName('td'));
                    expect(cells.count()).toEqual(7);
                    expect(cells[0].getText()).toBe(bamSummary.applicationSummaries[i].application.name);
                
                }
            })

Comment: @Sanja is it still failing?

Comment: I fixed it but had to use promises. Tried your approach but it didn´t work